# Is there any quasi-compact space which is not a quotient of any compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: gn.general-topology

> Is there any quasi-compact (= compact, possibly non-Hausdorff) space which is not a quotient of any compact Hausdorff space?

I strongly suspect the answer is yes, yet I couldn't come up with an example so far.

Comment: What about an infinite countable set with the compact topology whose nonempty open subsets are the cofinite subsets? I don't see at the moment whether it's quotient of a Hausdorff compact space.

Comment: I also suspect most of affine algebraic varieties with Zariski topology would be such examples, but again I have no proof or disproof of this.

Comment: Any such space would be compactly generated, maybe this gives some hints.

Comment: "Quotient" here has a different definition than [the usual one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)), I guess.  It should be a new topology on X, rather than on the set of equivalence classes?

Comment: It is the usual one, not the identification space. Although examples involving identification space is of course welcome. But this is equivalent to the quotient case, since identification map is just a quotient map onto a closed subspace.

Comment: @NateEldredge I've understood the question with the usual definition of quotient topology.

Comment: Here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2794129/94514 is a proof that the one point compactification of the rationals is not a continuous image of (so it is not a quotient of)  a compact Hausdorff space.